# Ant Replace Task in FTP Files

Tags: ant, ftp, replace

Is there a way to call the Ant replace task on files in an FTP?  I have a project with some static IDs in the code that change depending on whether I am on development platform or production.  I setup my and build.xml file to copy all my files to FTP, but I need to change those static IDs either on the way to the FTP or when they hit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to do `replace` within the `ant ftp` task, it looks like this is not supported.  But you could do a replace followed by ftp.

```
<replace dir="${ftp.src} token="@@@" value="replaced"/>
<ftp server="server" userid="user" password="password">
    <fileset dir="${ftp.src}"/>
</ftp>
```

Or perhaps you are looking for something different.

Comment: The problem that I would have doing that is that I would need to call another replace after the ftp task.  I think what I am going to have to do is copy the files to a temp directory, call the replace, then FTP that temp directory.

Answer (score 1):

Ant doesnot have inbulit replace task.
I achieved it by calling "del" first and than used "put", as below.

```
<ftp action="del" server="%ftpservername%" userid="%ftpserver_user%" password="%ftpserver_pwd%">
    <fileset>
                <include name="%file1%.db" />
                <include name="%file2%.db" />
    </fileset>
</ftp>  
<ftp action="put" retriesAllowed="-1" remotedir="%dest_dir%" server="%ftpservername%" port="%ftpport%" userid="%ftpserver_user%" password="%ftpserver_pwd%" binary="yes">
     <fileset dir="%src_dir%">
                <include name="%file1%.db" />
                <include name="%file2%.db" />
    </fileset>          
</ftp>
```

we can also do for directory which is in ant.apache.org